# Default region ignored in misd-service-development/phone-number-bundle

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using [misd-service-development/phone-number-bundle](https://github.com/misd-service-development/phone-number-bundle) with Symfony3. The input field for phone number consists of two fields: select with countries and the simple input text for the rest of the number. What I'm trying to do is to have default country (region) selected when creating a record in form.

Entity column looks like this:

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="phone_number", nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @AssertPhoneNumber(defaultRegion="PL")
 */
private $phoneOne;
```

...and builder function for creating field looks like this:

```
->add('phoneOne', PhoneNumberType::class, [
    'label' => 'Telefon 1',
    'widget' => PhoneNumberType::WIDGET_COUNTRY_CHOICE,
    'default_region' => 'PL',
    'preferred_country_choices' => [
        'PL', 'CN', 'DE', 'GB', 'FR',
    ],
])
```

...but on the select field the default selected option is still "CN" since it is first according to alphabetical order. Or do I understand "default region" in a wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I have the same issue, what I have done to fix this is by creating a form extension and override the buildView method like this

```
class PhoneNumberTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $default_region = $options['default_region'];
        if($default_region !== PhoneNumberUtil::UNKNOWN_REGION){
            $form->get('country')->setData($default_region);
        }
        parent::buildView($view, $form, $options);
    }


    /**
     * Returns the name of the type being extended.
     *
     * @return string The name of the type being extended
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return PhoneNumberType::class;
    }
}
```

In `services.yml`

```
restauprive.phone_number_type_extension:
    class: UserBundle\Form\Extension\PhoneNumberTypeExtension
    tags:
        - { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Form\Type\PhoneNumberType}
```